# Show that every group $G$ is isomorphic to a permutation group

Tags: group-theory

Cayley's Theorem states that "every group $G$ is isomorphic to a permutation group". But in every book we only get it for finite groups. Can anyone please help me to solve this for every group.

Comment: What part of the proof you know for finite groups doesn't apply to infinite groups?

Comment: @take008 To a subgroup of a _full symmetric group_. There are lots of permutation groups that aren't $S_n$.

Comment: @Arthur my bad, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Arthur huh oh yeah, it was correctly expressed in the OP since the start.

Answer (score 2):

Every group is isomorphic to a permutation group, irrespective of cardinality. The only difference is how to define the appropriate symmetric group to embed the group into. If $G$ is finite then the standard idea is to embed $G$ into the symmetric group $S_{n}$ where $n=|G|$. We can work more generally by defining $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ to be the set of bijections from the *set* $G$ to $G$ (so permutations on the set underlying $G$). If $G$ is finite then there is a clear bijection between $S_{|G|}$ and $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$.

The rest of the proof is identical.

I suspect the reason that introductory textbooks only prove Cayley's theorem for finite groups is because they are focusing on finite permutation groups. Infinite permutation groups are rather different, and it is sensible to avoid them in a first text. For example, there is no analogue of the alternating group for infinite symmetric groups, although a relatively easy tweak in the definition of these symmetric group does give us infinite alternating groups.

Comment: Part of the reason is that infinite groups were introduced much later than finite groups (and that "group" before 1880 is what is now known as "finite permutation group").

Comment: @YCor I hadn't thought of that, but that does make sense. History matters: I once tried to read Burnside's book, and was intrigued to discover how similar the coarse outline of his book was to the outline of my undergraduate studies over 100 years later.